# Enviar un valor a una columna en datatable con javascript

Tags: javascript, datatable

Tengo el siguiente `datatable`:

```
function configureTablePackingList(dataTableResult){

    var i = 1;
    var dataSet = [];
    $.each(
            dataTableResult,
            function(k,v){
                if(dataTableResult =! null){
                    dataSet.push([
                        v.Numero,
                        v.Garantia,
                        v.Fecha_de_cierre,
                        v.Numero_de_material,
                        v.Descripcion,
                        v.Cantidad_Autorizada,
                        v.Serie,
                        v.Costo_total,
                        v.Modelo,
                        "<input id='cmn-toggle-"+v.Numero+"' class='cmn-toggle-compro2 cmn-toggle-round-compro2' type='checkbox' name='noEnviados' onchange='activepopdt(this.id)'/><label for='cmn-toggle-"+v.Numero+"' class='activepop' id='motivo'></label>",
                        v.Motivo
                        ])
                }
            });



    $('#example2').DataTable({
        "bInfo" : false,
        "paging": true,
        "attr"  :  {
            "data-toggle": "alerta-contentalerta-maxi",
            "data-target": "#mb-motivo"
        },
        "autoWidth" : false,
        "bLengthChange" : true,
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "pageLength" : 10,
        "sSearch" : "Search all columns:",
        "columns":[
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recoleccion",

            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recolecciont",
            },
            {
                "class" : "responsive recolecciont",

            }        ]
    ,
    "columnDefs" : [ {
        "targets" : "_all"
    } ],

    "pagingType" : "simple_numbers",
    "searching" : true,

    "language" : {
        "url" : "js/DataTables/Spanish.json"
    },
    "aaData" : dataSet
        });
    document.getElementById(HTML_IDIVTBL_RESULTPACKINGIST).style.display = HTML_DIV_VISIBLE;
}
```

y en la columna de motivo le quiero pasar un valor de acuerdo a una selección de un **pop up**, que se activa al activar el **toogle button** cuando selecciono opción deseo pasar "perdí la pieza" en motivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto lo hago mediante **javascript**.

> ¿cómo puedo enviarle por medio de una función un valor a esta columna
>   "motivo" usando javascript? o ¿qué otra opción me podrían aconsejar?.

De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda. mi tabla se llama "example2"

[image: tabla]

Comment: ¿Cómo abres tu `modal` y cuál es el elemento que lo abre al hacer click sobre él? No has puesto el código relativo a esta parte.

Comment: despues de V.Modelo el fragmento de html ahí trazo el html y dentro el activepop es el que hace que lo muestre. Saudos

Comment: tambien utilizo un onclick y llamo esta funcion:

Comment: function activepopdt(id) {
 $("#backpop").css("display", "block");
    if ($('#'+id).prop('checked')) {
     
     $("#mb-motivo").css("display", "block");
     css={
          "position": 'absolute',
             "display": 'flex',
             "justify-content": 'center',
             "align-items": 'center',
             "width": '100%',
             "height": '100%',
             "top": '0',
             "left": '0',
             "z-index": '1000',
          };
          $("#mb-motivo").css(css);}else {

Comment: Adrián, todas estas explicaciones debes añadirlas a la pregunta. Explicar bien el problema y ayudar a los demás a reproducirlo es una de las claves para obtener una respuesta.

Comment: ¿cual es la duda?